# How do I fix my code so that it prints the largest and lowest values in a matrix?

Tags: sorting, matrix

```
def largestlowest(matrix):
        largeset = 0
        lowest = 0

        for row in range(len(matrix)):
            for col in range(len(matrix[row]-1)):
                if matrix[col] > matrix[col+1]:
                    largest = matrix[col]
            if matrix[col] < matrix[col+1]:
                lowest = matrix[col]
        else:
            print("there is no min/max value")
            return largest and lowest

print(largestlowest([[4,8,2,9,34,57,22,44], [1,2,8,9,1,2,55,3,22,4]]))
```

Comment: You're comparing the wrong things. And assigning wrong things too (your largest/lowest would be arrays, not scalars)

Comment: Rows have different length. What kind of matrix is that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to **mention the language**. I assume this is python. Also **try to run and test** the code before posting it. This code is not running at all.

This is the running version of the code you submitted in python:

```
def largestlowest(matrix):
    largeset = 0
    lowest = 0
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix[row])-1):
            if (matrix[row][col] > matrix[row][col+1]):
                largest = matrix[row][col]
            if (matrix[row][col] < matrix[row][col+1]):
                lowest = matrix[row][col]

     return (largest, lowest)

print(largestlowest([[4,8,2,9,34,57,22,44], [1,2,8,9,1,2,55,3,22,4]]))
```

> Note that to access an element of a list you should call it by both `row` and `column` : `matrix[row][col]`.

There are a few things wrong:

- You go up to `(len(matrix[row])-1)` and therefore do not include the
  last column.
- Then you compare neighboring elements `matrix[row][col] > matrix[row][col+1]` instead of comparing all of them with the lowest and the largest.
- You assign the lowest to 0, which will always be lower than all of your elements
- `return a and b` will return `a` only

I recommend you search each step (e.g *how to call a matrix element in python*). You will find plenty of information online. Try to run the code as quickly as possible and solve the errors in the console. 
Finally, the code that does what you want (I think):

```
def largestlowest(matrix):
    if (not len(matrix)):
        return ("Matrix should have at least one element!")
    ## assign largest and lowest to first element of martix
    largest = lowest = matrix[0][0]
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
            if (matrix[row][col] > largest):
                largest = matrix[row][col]
            if (matrix[row][col] < lowest):
                lowest = matrix[row][col]

    # return (largest, lowest)
    return "Largest element of matrix: %d, lowest element of matrix: %d" % (largest, lowest)
print(largestlowest([[4,8,2,9,34,57,22,44], [1,2,8,9,1,2,55,3,22,4]]))
print(largestlowest([]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was actually comparing the wrong values:
`if matrix[col] > matrix[col+1]:` isn't comparing the current value to the largest, it is comparing it to the one after it. The same thing was happening for the small.

Also, you were handling your data incorrectly. `matrix[col]` is an array itself, not an individual element (at least, according to the example you gave).

The code below is commented and works. It outputs:

```
LARGEST: 57
LOWEST: 1

# Function
def largestlowest(matrix):
        # Declaring biggest and smallest variable. Setting extraneous at first
        largest = -10000
        lowest = 10000

        # Loop through every array in the matrix as you have defined it
        for arr in matrix:
            # Loop through each item in the array
            for item in arr:
                # If it is bigger than the largest, set the largest to be that value
                if item > largest:
                    largest = item
                # If it is smaller than the smallest, set the smallest to be that value
                if item < lowest:
                    lowest = item

        # Return the largest and lowest
        return largest, lowest

# Example main function
def main():
    # Define a test matrix (copied from your example)
    matrix = [[4,8,2,9,34,57,22,44], [1,2,8,9,1,2,55,3,22,4]]
    # Run the function we created
    largest, lowest = largestlowest(matrix)

    # Print out the results
    print("LARGEST: ", largest)
    print("LOWEST: ", lowest)

# Call the main function
main()
```